# Is there an option to install an npm package without dependencies?

Tags: npm

I'm attemting to modify an npm package with multiple dependencies. As such `npm install -g .` takes a long time to execute. Do I have other options besides removing the dependencies from packages.json?

Comment: I think this question is a better fit for SO, and was asked there before this one - [Install only one package from package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420564/install-only-one-package-from-package-json). It also has updated answers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I believe it belongs to SO, and had been asked there already.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**--no-optional** option is now implemented according to this documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install :

```
The --no-optional argument will prevent optional dependencies from being installed.
```

Answer (score 14):

If you're developing that `node_module` yourself, don't waste your time on `npm install`s, instead use `npm link`.

In short, you create a symbolic link to your module folder on an npm-owned global folder, and then in your app folder you ask npm to use that symbolic linked folder.

This makes changes you make in the module folder to be reflected immediately in your app.

Here are the main steps (copied from the tutorial linked below, make sure to read the tutorial for important gotchas):

1. cd to `src/my_module`
2. Run "`npm link`". This creates a symbolic link from a global folder to the `src/my_module` folder.
3. cd to `src/my_app`
4. Run `npm link my_module`. This links `node_modules/my_module` in this particular project to the global folder, so that `require` calls
   looking for `my_module` wind up loading it from your development folder,
   `src/my_module`.

See this tutorial: http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears
And the official docs for `npm link`: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: Not changing my accepted answer, but upvoting because this is useful for my specific case.

Answer (score 10):

This feature was requested back in 2010, but unfortunately was ignored and closed: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/340

I tried a bunch of options, and finally found a pretty simple solution - rename package.json to something else before doing npm install, then revert it back to after install finishes:

```
mv package.json package.bak
npm install <package_name> --no-save
mv package.bak package.json
```

Comment: Wow, is that seriously still the only way? That's ridiculous, there should be a flag `--ignore-package` or something.

Comment: This solution is good and so far it may be the best solution for my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532845/how-to-install-only-babel-related-devdependencies-in-package-json

Answer (score 7):

Looking through [the docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html) it doesn't appear to have an option beyond the `--no-optional` switch.

#### Untested/uncomfirmed

This SO Q&A titled: [`npm install` installs all dependencies of my project over the network, even if they are already installed or available from cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538899/npm-install-installs-all-dependencies-of-my-project-over-the-network-even-if) would seem to imply there's a `--skip-installed` switch. But the docs do not make any reference to this switch.